# How to return a function inside a function (as opposed to echo)

Tags: php, wordpress, api

So, in order to get this code working, I need to output the function "get_flickr_rss" via a return rather than an echo... I believe the reason this code is not working for me is because the "get_flickr_rss" function itself is somehow defaulting to an echo rather than a return.  How can I call the function to force it to return rather than echoing?

```
function generate_flickr_rss($atts, $content = null) {
    // default parameters
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'set' => '72157625809767439',
        'photos' => '20'
    ), $atts));
    // Call FLickrRSS Hook
    return get_flickrRSS(array('set' => $set, 'num_items' => $photos, 'type' => 'set'));
}
```

I tried the following code to reverse engineer it as a return, but unfortunately, no dice.

```
function generate_flickr_rss($atts) {
    // default parameters
    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'set' => '72157625809767439',
        'photos' => '20'
    ), $atts));
    // Call FLickrRSS Hook
    $flickr_rss_return = get_flickrRSS(array('set' => $set, 'num_items' => $photos, 'type' => 'set'));
    return $flickr_rss_return;
}

add_shortcode('flickr_rss', 'generate_flickr_rss');

add_shortcode('flickr_rss', 'generate_flickr_rss');
```

Comment: can't really do nothin' about that unless you change get_flickrRSS() ...perhaps there is a flag argument to make it return instead of output (or perhaps you have access to change the function yourself?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With output buffering you can catch the output of the function.

```
ob_start();
get_flickrRSS(...);
return ob_get_clean();
```

Of course you should rather change the function to return it's output, but I guess that's impossible for a reason. ;-)

Comment: Got it!  Will accept this answer when StackOverflow lets me :)

Comment: very much a last resort, you could make a copy of get_flickrRSS() call it get_flickrRSS_return() and change the echo to a return, this wont interfere with anything else using the function but is not ideal

Answer (score 1):

I took a look at the WP plugin [flickrRSS](http://eightface.com/wordpress/flickrrss/) and the changes aren't that great.

In the function `printGallery`, there are a number of `echo` statements. Replace these with lines that concatenate the echoed string to a `$result` variable that your define as an empty string at the beginning of the function.

Then, return `$result` at the end of the `printGallery` function. Then, modify `get_flickrRSS` to `return` or `echo` this string according to your needs (as defined by another input parameter).

Of course, all of this will get overwritten the next time the plugin is updated, so I suggest pointing the plugin writer to this Stack Overflow page and asking him to modify the plugin to support your needs long term :)

Comment: Good point.  Can someone explain why output buffering is not ideal? I would love to have top notch code, but not at the risk of constantly updating when there's a version update... not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$foo = get_flickrRSS(.....;
return $foo;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  Output buffering in the answer above has come to the rescue.

Comment: its not ideal, but its your call, alternative listed below